# GCP create load balancer via api

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, sdk, load-balancing, gcp-load-balancer

I want to create a load balancer (TCP) via a REST API or Python SDK for GCP.

I haven't found any solutions so far.

Example from UI :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the API's perspective, there is no "Load Balancer API", just the various compute components that make up a load balancer, such as forwarding rules and url maps.

More details on the APIs for those individual components here: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/apis